# AppleScript on Windows

Tags: windows, applescript

I would like to use AppleScript on Windows. Is there any IDE or Windows port ?

Comment: There's a clue in the name - AppleScript is an Apple technology found only in Mac OS.

Comment: You may get a better answer if you describe what you are trying to accomplish instead of what tools you have.

Answer (score 16):

Not as far as I know, but you have a variety of other (free) options on Windows:

- [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/)
- [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
- [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28VS.85%29.aspx) ([Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/default.asp))
- ...

Comment: vbscript i think this the closest thing to applescript but Idk I've only every worked on apple

Comment: while different in style, you might find Python to be similar in ease of use - that's what I switched to when I started working on a PC.

Comment: +1 on VBScript in both the answer and comments. That has similar cross-application automation hooks that Applescript was designed for. But, Applescript isn't available in any form on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

apple script is used to control mac programs so it isn't available on windows you will only find things similar to apple script

Answer (score 1):

There isn't Applescript for Windows, but you can use similar scripting languages on Windows, even if none of them is compatible with Applescript.
I would try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml).